# Way to merge faces after remesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces, remesh

I'm trying to get my head around remeshing and currently struggling to see the advantages... as I just end up with an insane amount of faces if I want the object to resemble its original shape?

Take this letter M for example... I had to set the 'sharp' remesh value to 10 and ended up with so many faces that they are like 1px each on my screen.

Is there no way I can merge the faces together? Say like, those that are on the same side as each other.

I feel like that would make things a lot more efficient

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe try a X > Limited Dissolve?

Comment: Why do you even try to remesh that model to begin with? A shape so simple, I woudln't even bother unless I really need to. And if so, I would just dissolve limited, make a couple cuts myself and i'd be done way better and cleaner than what any of Blender's remeshing methods can do.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! I couldn't find Limited Dissolve but found the normal Dissolve feature... that combined with 'select / similar' worked nicely, although it did nearly crash Blender in the process lol

Comment: In Edit mode select all and press X >Limited Dissolve

Comment: @moonboots Thank you!

Comment: But as Lolock says it would be interesting to know what you're trying to do, why did you subdivide your mesh for example?

Comment: @moonboots To be honest I dont specifically need to remesh this object, more like I'm trying to learn just for future reference. As a lot of the YouTube tutorials that I follow involve remeshing objects, but it puts a lot of strain on my machine despite me having a high-end M1 MacBook Pro